# How many touch points does the Google Nexus 10 support?

Tags: android, device

I would like to do some Android 4.2 coding and need a device and API that supports at least 10 touch points. Would the Google Nexus 10 be suitable for this?

Comment: Not really a programming question, is it?

Comment: @fiddler: Considering that the 9th word is "coding", one would presume that this is a programming question.

Comment: However I perceive it more like a hardware oriented question, but I may be wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Nexus 10 appears to support `jazzhands`, based on the results of the MultiTouch Tester app.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to jazzhands! Google Support just confirmed that apps on the Nexus 10 can read at least 10 touch points